# Simple C Shell Command

Tags: c, linux, shell, command

I have most of the logic for my simple C shell command but I am having problems with the last part. Also the void exec_cmd_red_out and void exec_cmd_red_in may need to be looked at to run the desired output. What code should I input into void exec_cmd_pipe to receive my desired output with the code I have so far?

```
 This shell will be able to process command lines in the following forms:
          •command [args]
          •command [args] > file(output redirected to write to file)
          •command [args] < file(input redirected to read from file)
          •command1 [args1] | command2 [args2](output of command1piped into input of command2)
```

This is the part I am having problems with:

```
  // Create a pipline between the first command and the second command
  void exec_cmd_pipe(char *args1[], char *args2[]) {
  // YOUR CODE HERE
   }
```

This is what I need to do for the exec_cmd_pipe:

```
   void exec_cmd_pipe(char *args1[], char *args2[])
      1.Create a child process using fork.
      2.The child process should do the following:
          (a)Create a pipe.
          (b)If the pipe creation fails, diplsay an error and exit the child process.
          (c)Create a second child process.
          (d)The second child process should redirect standard output to write to the pipe 
          input, execute the command, and display an error and exit if execution fails.
          (e)The first child process should redirect standard input to write to the pipe 
            output, execute the command, and display an error and exit if execution fails.
      3.The parent process should wait for the first child process to complete
```

Here is my code for this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

const int MAX_LINE = 256;
const int MAX_ARGS = 64;

int split_cmd(char *cmd, char *args[]);
void process_args(char *args[], int count);

void exec_cmd(char *args[]);
void exec_cmd_red_out(char *args[], char *filename);
void exec_cmd_red_in(char *args[], char *filename);
void exec_cmd_pipe(char *args1[], char *args2[]);

int main()
{
    // The command line string
    char cmd[MAX_LINE];

    // The comand line broken into arguments
    char *args[MAX_ARGS];

    // Repeatedly prompt for a command and execute it
    while(1) {
        // Display prompt and read the command line
        printf("> ");
        fgets(cmd, MAX_LINE, stdin);

        // Process the command
        int count = split_cmd(cmd, args);
        process_args(args, count);
    }

    return 0;
}

// Break the command into command line arguments
int split_cmd(char *cmd, char *args[]) {
    int index = 0;

    // Extract each comand line argument and store it in args
    char *arg = strtok(cmd, " \t\n\v\f\r");
    while(arg != NULL && index < MAX_ARGS - 1) {
        args[index] = arg;
        arg = strtok(NULL, " \t\n\v\f\r");
        index++;
    }
    args[index] = NULL;
    return index;
}

// Takes an array of command line arguments and an argument count and processes
// the command line
void process_args(char *args[], int count) {

    // Find the location of the delimiter (|, <, or >)
    int i, delim = -1;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(strcmp(args[i], "|") == 0 ||
                strcmp(args[i], "<") == 0 ||
                strcmp(args[i], ">") == 0)
            delim = I;
    }

    // If user entered a blank line do nothing
    if(count == 0)
        return;

    // If user entered exit, then exit the shell
    else if(count == 1 && strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) {
        puts("[exiting smash]\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    // If there are no pipes or redirects, execute the command
    else if(delim < 0)
        exec_cmd(args);

    // Pipe or redirect appears as the first or last argument
    else if(delim == 0 || delim == count - 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "smash: sytnax error\n");

    // Redirect output
    else if(strcmp(args[delim], ">") == 0) {
        args[delim] = NULL;
        exec_cmd_red_out(args, args[delim+1]);
    }

    // Redirect input
    else if(strcmp(args[delim], "<") == 0) {
        args[delim] = NULL;
        exec_cmd_red_in(args, args[delim+1]);
    }

    // Pipe
    else if(strcmp(args[delim], "|") == 0) {
        args[delim] = NULL;
        exec_cmd_pipe(args, &args[delim+1]);
    }

    // If this point is reached something went wrong with this code
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "smash: internal error");
    }
}

// Execute the command
void exec_cmd(char *args[]) {

    // Fork a child process
    pid_t pid = fork();

    // Child process
    if(pid == 0) {
        // Execute the command
        execvp(args[0], args);
        fprintf(stderr, "smash: %s: command not found\n", args[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Parent process
    else {
        // Wait for the child to complete
        wait(NULL);
    }
}

// Redirect output to write to the given file, then execute the command
void exec_cmd_red_out(char *args[], char *filename) {
    // Child process
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // Create a new file with the given name
        FILE *newFile = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (newFile == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create file %s\n", filename);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Close the file
        fclose(newFile);

        // Execute the command
        if (execvp(args[0], args) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "smash: %s: command not found\n", args[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
    else {
        // Wait for child process to complete
        wait(NULL);
    }
}



// Redirect input to read from the given file, then execute the command
void exec_cmd_red_in(char *args[], char *filename) {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    // Child process
    if(pid == 0){
        // open the file
        FILE *fileptr;
        fileptr = fopen(filename, "r");
        if(fileptr == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "%s file not found\n", filename);
            exit(0);
        }
        // Execute the command
        execvp(args[0], args);
        fprintf(stderr, "smash: %s command not found\n", args[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // parent process
    else{
        // wait for the child to complete
        wait(NULL);
    }
}

// Create a pipline between the first command and the second command
void exec_cmd_pipe(char *args1[], char *args2[]) {
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid = fork();
    int n_pipes=2; //pipes needed
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n_pipes; i++){
    int oldfd = 0;
    int newfd;
    if(fd[0]!=0){
    close(fd[1]);
    oldfd = fd[0];
     }
    pipe(fd);
    if(pid == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "smash: ");
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else if(pid == 0){
    dup2(newfd, 1); 
    close(fd[0]);
    execvp(args1[0], args1);

   }else if(pid == 1){
   dup2(newfd, 1);
   close(fd[0]);
   execvp(args2[0], args2);
  }else{
            // wait for the child to complete
            wait(NULL);
    }
  }
  }
```

Output desired:

```
  $ ./smash
  > ls
  [name of your c file].c smash
  > ls -l
  total 32
  -rw-r--r-- 1 smithj staff 2146 Sep 25 16:04 [name of your c file].c
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 smithj staff 9076 Sep 25 16:05 smash
  >
  > fnord
  smash: command fnord not found.
  > ls > listing.txt
  > cat < listing.txt
  [name of your c file].c
  listing.txt
  smash
  > ls -l | sort
  -rw-r--r-- 1 smithj staff 2146 Sep 25 16:04 [name of your c file].c
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 smithj staff 9076 Sep 25 16:05 smash
  total 32
  > exit
  [exiting seashell]
```

Comment: Provide an attempt to write `exec_cmd_pipe()`, then we can help you finding errors and such. Also, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36897690/combining-two-commands-with-a-pipe), it may help you.

Comment: Here is my attemp. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never `fork()` in the `exec_cmd_pipe` function. The `pid` is never initialised. You could have caught this had you enabled compiler warnings and errors.

Comment: @Pete - `In function ‘process_args’:
… error: ‘I’ undeclared …             delim = I;`